# Sublime text change the indentation according to the file extension

Tags: html, ruby, sublimetext3, indentation

I know how to change default indentation in the file : preferences of sublime text but i would like to know if it's possible to tell to sublimetext : when it's a .rb file you have to set 2 for tab size and when it's a .html you have 4 for tab size.
Is it possible to make it automatic ?

Answer (score 2):

In your Ruby syntax settings `$SUBLIME_PATH/Packages/User/Ruby.sublime-settings` set `tab_size` = 4

```
{
  "tab_size": 4 // by the way it is 2 for Ruby by conventions
}
```

For HTML set `tab_size` in `$SUBLIME_PATH/Packages/User/HTML.sublime-settings`

```
{
  "tab_size": 2
}
```

OR you can open an HTML file and go to **preferences > settings - syntax specific** and sublime will open the settings file for HTML.